# How to display cost Powerbi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two columns - Customer Paid (which is displayed as a "y" (yes) or "n" (no) and the second column will have the cost.

I cannot figure out a way to get both columns to coincide. I did get the percentage to display for how many times the customer paid but want the actual cost of when they did and when they did not.

New to Power BI, any help is appreciated, thank you

[image: Matrix]

Answer (score 0):

From your requirements you need to use Calculate, to get the cost of those paid would be to create a measure:

```
Paid Cost = CALCULATE(SUM([Cost Total]), FILTER(TableName, [Customer Paid] = "y"))
```

Put the name of your table in 'TableName'
This will work out the sum total for all Customer, by filtering the table with your 'y' flag. Replace the 'y' with an 'n' when creating a new measure to get the total of customers not paid.